# JOIN two tables but only return rows with unique values in one field

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a table of `Currency CHAR(3)` : StressValue `(FLOAT)` pairs.
It has 6 rows.

The 6th row's `'Currency'` value is `'GRP'` which represents a group of currencies that are specified in a second table of `Currency` : `StressValue` pairs.

I want to joing the two tables on 'Currency' but I don't want to return those rows in the 2nd table that have the same 'Currency' value contained in any of the 5 rows in the first table.

For example if row 2 has the combo `'GBP`' : '0.05' and the 2nd (ie. `'GRP'`) table has the row 'GBP' : `'0.10'` then I want the result set to show only one `'GBP'` row - the one being `'0.05'`.

Please, can someone suggest the best way to do this in SQL Server 2008 R2?

EDIT:

Below are the two tables in a simple LEFT JOIN of Dimension1=GroupName.
The problem is I have 'ES' with two values: -0.04 and -0.045 and I only want to keep the -0.04 one.

[image]
EDIT 2:

Left table, Right table and Desired Result set:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Note that the row for GroupName='PE' AND 'MemberName='ES' has been excluded from the desired result set as 'ES' already appears in the Left table.

Comment: How do your tables and data look like? Can share with us? :-)

Comment: please show us the table values without left join or so.. and also please show us how you want your output resultset?

Comment: If I understand you right, you're looking for `AND NOT EXISTS( SELECT * from Table1 as filter WHERE filter.Dimension1 = JoinedTable.Dimension1 )` as an extra criterium for the join?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming I understand you right:

```
select * from
Currency as c
left join StressValue as s on c.Diemention1 = s.GroupName AND s.MemberName <> ( 
  SELECT s.MemberName 
  from Currency as c 
  join StressValue as s 
  on c.Diemention1 = s.MemberName)
```

see [FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/eaf9f/13)